# SharePoint with large data

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, large-data

I want to discussion about SharePoint  2013 we are go on to development correspondence transaction system as product for our company on SharePoint 2013 , we expect a large data with large transaction on correspondence  list we want your experience about this issue so please can you help us in this we have tow option :

development with sql database

development with SharePoint list

so please want your helpful answer with details

Comment: Can you define "large data with large transaction" for us? Do you mean large file size and a large amount of files? If so, how big and how many? How many transactions per day/hour/minute are you anticipating?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience SharePoint is not very good to store huge amount of records (hundred thousands or even millions) in list. The reason is in the way data is stored in SharePoint database - if you check SharePoint content database you will find that all records from all lists on particular site collection are stored in one table AllListsData. The table itself is not really normalized so queries are not really fast and you get some performance loss because of the use of SharePoint as middle-ware. Moreover because all data from all lists are stored in one table if you have one huge list on site collection then it could degrade performance of whole site collection.

If you really need SharePoint I would suggest you to use separate sql database to store data and use [BCS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163782%28v=office.15%29.aspx) functionality to access it from SharePoint. Using this approach you can normalize data in your separate database and access data from SharePoint.

Comment: can you explain to me in code how you will get the data from data base and how to use the workflow with the tables in the data base

Comment: I'm not sure that you can use BCS with workflows. You should try it.

Answer (score 0):

To get around it with the client Object Model you can use this code snippet, it uses item pos to leverage getting more than 5000K items. if you need VB.NET or more in-depth breakdown this is the site for you [here](http://www.guideushow.com/quick-and-easy/client-object-model-handling-lists-over-5000-sharepoint-2013-sharepoint-online/) [The Snippet is from here](http://www.guideushow.com/quick-and-easy/client-object-model-handling-lists-over-5000-sharepoint-2013-sharepoint-online/)

```
List list = ClientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(“Assets”);
ListItemCollectionPosition itemPosition = null;
while (true) {
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = itemPosition;
camlQuery.ViewXml = “<View>” + Constants.vbCr + Constants.vbLf + “<ViewFields>” +     Constants.vbCr + Constants.vbLf + “<FieldRef Name=’Id’/><FieldRef Name=’Title’/><FieldRef Name=’Serial_No’/><FieldRef Name=’CRM_ID’/>” + Constants.vbCr + Constants.vbLf + “</ViewFields>” + Constants.vbCr + Constants.vbLf + “<RowLimit>2201</RowLimit>” + Constants.vbCr + Constants.vbLf + ” </View>”;
ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientcontext.Load(listItems);
clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
itemPosition = listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition;
foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems) {
Console.WriteLine(“Item Title: {0} Item Key: {1} CRM ID: {2}”, listItem(“Title”), listItem(“Serial_x0020_No_x002e_”), listItem(“CRM_ID”));
}
if (itemPosition == null) {
break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit While
}
Console.WriteLine(itemPosition.PagingInfo);
Console.WriteLine();
}
```